# "prompt()" not recording it's answer for a setInterval function

Tags: javascript, setinterval, prompt

## **EDIT:I have decided to make a manual refresh button rather than have it auto refresh**

I am trying to create a live chat system using google sheets and google forms, I thought I would add a way to change the refresh rate, so I added a button to change the amount of time in seconds between refreshes, but what I enter in the prompt doesn't seem to change the refresh rate. Any help is greatly appreciated!!! (also note that "urlforgooglesheets" or "urlforgoogleform" are not the actual URLs I have entered, I just put them like that for the code shown below)

```js
window.onload = function refresh() {
  var sheet = document.getElementById("formSheet");
  var refreshRate = document.getElementById("refreshButton");
  refreshRate.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var waitPrompt = prompt("After how many seconds should chat refresh?");
  });
  setInterval(function() {
    var waitTime = waitPrompt * 1000;
    sheet.src = "#";
    setTimeout(function() {
      sheet.outerHTML = '<iframe id="formSheet" src="urlforthegooglesheets" height="550" width="453" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
    }, 10);
  }, waitTime);
}
```

```html
<button id="refreshButton">Change Refresh Rate</button>
<iframe src="urlforgoogleform" width="525" height="580" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading…</iframe>
<iframe id="formSheet" src="urlforthegooglesheet" height="580" width="453" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: I don't see your first `setInterval()` code being hit because `waitTime` is undefined as it's being used here. You use it when creating the interval before it has any value.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the error code, you can see that on line 13 of your JS codeblock, `waitTime` is not defined. This is because you define `waitTime` inside of the setInterval callback. You will also want to store the number returned by `setInterval()` as a global variable so that you can change the `waitTime`, and to change that you need to `clearInterval()` to prevent multiple intervals going on at once. I'm also going to put the default waiting as a variable at the top, you should remove this and put whatever you want as the default.

```js
var waitInterval;
var defaultWait = 1;
window.onload = function refresh() {
  var sheet = document.getElementById("formSheet");
  var refreshRate = document.getElementById("refreshButton");
  refreshRate.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var waitPrompt = prompt("After how many seconds should chat refresh?");
    clearInterval(waitInterval);
    var waitTime = waitPrompt * 1000;
    waitInterval = setInterval(function() {
      sheet.src = "#";
      setTimeout(function() {
        sheet.outerHTML = '<iframe id="formSheet" src="urlforthegooglesheets" height="550" width="453" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
      }, 10);
    }, waitTime);
  });
  var waitTime = defaultWait * 1000;
  waitInterval = setInterval(function() {
    sheet.src = "#";
    setTimeout(function() {
      sheet.outerHTML = '<iframe id="formSheet" src="urlforthegooglesheets" height="550" width="453" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
    }, 10);
  }, waitTime);
}
```

This code doesn't show errors, but I can't test this with Google Sheets to know if it works. Another thing to do is move the `waitInterval = setInterval(...)` into its own seperate function, but that's not necessary.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't seem to do the setInterval after entering things into the prompt, I could just be doing something wrong tho, the only thing I changed in the one you provided me is the defaultWait to 10 :/